# Frequencies of Matter

Tags: frequency, vibrations, matter

Is it theoretically possible for physical solid matter to vibrate at a high enough frequency to become imperceptible to vision and move through other solid matter?

Comment: Not in this reality

Comment: Not really. What makes you think it would?

Comment: "Through" is never really "through". Even an electron passing "through" a material bounces on other electrons and passes trough the empty space. With this thought, the scenario where you have a particle of flour moving really fast in a sieve will make it impossible for your eyes to perceive it and it will eventually pass through the sieve :)

Comment: Any object could go through other by tunnel effect, but I guess this was not what you were thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it theoretically possible for physical solid matter to vibrate

Solid matter continually vibrates, and the vibrations are perceived macroscopically as temperature. It is the rotational and vibrational motion of the atoms and molecules which are bound together.

> at a high enough frequency

The temperature of a solid comes with a [black body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)  connected to it, and thus there exists a spectrum of characteristic frequencies, related to the frequencies of the vibrational and rotational levels of the atoms and molecules in the solid. The higher the temperature the higher the frequency, and the higher the frequency the higher the temperature.

> to become imperceptible to vision and move through other solid matter?

If the frequency gets high enough the solid will either burn, or melt, depending on the atoms and molecules involved. The result of high frequencies of vibration do not lead to metaphysical conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP is asking what seems like a metaphysical question, he or she might be on to something. If there were a theoretical material that did not get destroyed by physical vibrations in the hundreds of Terahertz range of frequencies, and somehow did not emit other radiation while doing so, it is possible that the material would become partially imperceptible to vision via the Doppler shifting of the reflected light. If the incident light is scattered into the UV range by the Doppler effect when the object is moving towards us and into the IR range when it is moving away from us over one vibrational cycle, then it would be imperceptible to the human eye during those periods. I would imagine that it would look somehow dimmer to the eye, or perhaps like a shadow.

For devices that use effects like this, see, e.g.:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_vibrometer